# Intellij IDEA and mvp4g APT annotation checking

Tags: gwt, intellij-idea, annotations, mvp4g

Was anyone able to configure annotation checking for mvp4g in their project?
For eclipse there is this plugin ( http://code.google.com/p/mvp4g/wiki/APT ) so I'm just wondering if it'll work with Intellij's IDEA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no experience with this, but in Idea 10.5 there is Settings -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors. You might give it a try.

Comment: So, Idea does not work with mvp4g? it could be use only with Eclipse??